# How to access a program running on localhost from another program running on localhost

Tags: url, localhost, port

I have two programs running on my local machine : a wordpress and a spring boot webservice
How can i access the webservice from the wordpress ? I've tried the following code ( It doesn't work without the "http://" either ) :

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://localhost:8088/hello');
```

of course the port and the path is correct, But It seems like two applications on localhost cannot communicate together Am I right ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone is facing a similar problem, the free solution is to use free argo tunnel service. I used Cloudflare and it works great, i think you can also use Ngrok.

There is a link that may help you : https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-free-argo-tunnel-for-your-next-project/